# Typescript module not found error after compilation

Tags: typescript

This has been driving me crazy. How can I get typescript to compile the imported module correctly? My main.ts has `import { AddListeners } from './listeners';` which is also a .ts file with `export function AddListeners()` but when compiled to main.js, this line doesn't change and node throws this error:

> Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\bugbe\Documents\VSCode\tricorder\dist\listeners' imported from C:\Users\bugbe\Documents\VSCode\tricorder\dist\main.js

Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2020",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "*":[
        "node_modules/"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

so the code to import the module is not be compile correctly because to work it should look like `import { AddListeners } from './listeners.js';`

Comment: `listeners.js` seems to be a javascript (not typescript) file. Is this correct?

Comment: I have main.ts and listeners.ts and the output folder contains their respective .js files.

Comment: FYI: deleting `node_modules` folder and running npm install fixes this issue whenever I encounter it

Answer (score 18):

I ran into this problem when compiling TS to ES modules with Node 15. Turns out that TS does not add the ".js" extension to your import paths automatically when compiling the modules, but the ES path resolution algorithm expects the extension to be present.

For me it was as simple as using the `--es-module-specifier-resolution=node` flag to get Node to use the old `require()` resolution behaviour:

```sh
node --es-module-specifier-resolution=node ./dist/src/main
```

---

For reference my setup is the following:

**package.json**

```json
{
    ...
    "type": "module"
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
    "include": ["src/**/*", "package.json"],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "composite": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationMap": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "module": "ESNext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "newLine": "LF",
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": false,
        "noUnusedParameters": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "strict": true,
        "target": "ES2018"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You should run the program with node using the flag `--es-module-specifier-resolution=node` because you are using es6+ Module type. If you are using CommonJS you wouldn't have this issue.

Comment: I dont have module set to es6, rather to commonjs, and still have this issue.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about your project and give me some more context so I can understand the issue?

Answer (score 3):

In Typescript source files, make sure to import other Typescript files with the .js extension.

```
import { AddListeners } from './listeners.js';
```

Allso in the tsconfig.json set the module to es6

```
"module": "ES6",
```

And make sure to set the type to module in the package.json.

```
"type": "module",
```

Comment: Definitely the simplest solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. In your tsconfig.json you have "module": "es2020". That means that typescript will compile your code to use ES modules. To run nodejs with ES modules you need v12 of nodejs and run it with the `--experimental-modules` flag or have nodejs version 13.2.0+ to run without the `--experimental-modules` flag.
2. If you cannot use newer versions of the nodejs you need to change `"module": "es2020"` to `"module": "CommonJS"`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you do not declare an enum in any `.d.ts` files. When you try to use an enum that declared in those type of files, it causes `Cannot find module error`.

Comment: Could you possibly explain why an enum would mess up an import like that?

Comment: @MarcSlothEastman I'm not entirely sure, but I think the reason for this might be that when compiling your TypeScript project, the .d.ts files are not being generated. Due to the absence of these files at runtime, NodeJS cannot find the relevant enums. Again, I'm not completely certain.

Answer (score -1):

In TS Files, Make sure your relative path are correct and not having wrong relative path.
Since, While clicking on it from TS file, you might be redirected to right path but in js build files, IT might be problematic issue while creating paths.